# Stop object from being displayed on multiple layers?

Tags: objects, layers

I accidentally clicked something, and now my object is on multiple layers. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>M</kbd> and select the layer you want it to be on.

[image]

Chances are, what you did, was press <kbd>M</kbd> and selected multiple layers by holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd>